# Can I show that $\int_{\gamma(0;r)} \frac{1}{z-a} dz = 0$ when $|a|>r>0$ without using Cauchy Theorem?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I encountered this problem as a previous result of an exercise in a text book way before proving Cauchy Theorem, so I think there must be another way to prove it without it.

> Show that $\int_{\gamma(0;r)} \frac{1}{z-a} dz = 0$ for $|a|>r>0$

Here is my try using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but I'm not sure if it is the right way to proceed.

Parametrize the circline by $\Gamma_r = re^{it}$ for $t\in \left[0,2\pi \right]$. Now $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-a}$ is holomorphic in the open disc $D(0;r)$, so there exist a function $F$ such that $f=F'$ in the disc (this is the step I think I got wrong). Then

$$\int_{\gamma(0;r)} \frac{1}{z-a} dz  =\int_{\gamma(0;r)} F'(z) dz = F(\gamma(2\pi))-F(\gamma(0))=F(r)-F(r)=0$$

Is this proof okay? And if not, can you help me to solve it properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $z$ is integrated along the path $\gamma(0;a)$ then what does the condition "for $|a| > |z|$" mean? Are you sure that the exercise is quoted correctly?

Comment: @MartinR You are right, the path is $\gamma(0;r)$ and the condition should be $|a|>r>0$. Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would consider using the fact that there exists such an $F$ to be using Cauchy's theorem, since the usual proof of this for arbitrary holomorphic functions on simply connected domains uses Cauchy's theorem.  But in this case you can avoid that by just writing down such an $F$ explicitly: $F(z)=\log(z-a)$, for some branch of $\log$ defined in the ball of radius $r$ around $-a$.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question, why can we say that $F(z)=\log (z-a)$ for some branch of log defined there? I always doubt when complex logarithm is involve.

Comment: Well, for instance, if $\operatorname{Re}(a)>0$, then the ball of radius $r$ around $-a$ does not intersect the positive real axis, so you can use that as a branch cut.  You can similarly choose branch cuts for other values of $a$.